# return false; Not working in Firefox in remote host but works in localhost

Tags: javascript

This is quite weird as I would expect the same behaviour in client side script.

HTML:

```
<button class="button1" onclick="validate(); return false;">Validate</button>
```

JS:

```
function validate(){

                alert('works');

            }
```

It works fine in the localhost, but in the remote host the page just updates, no alert.

If it's possible, I'd like a solution in plain javascript (i.e., no jQuery click event handlers).

Thanks in advance,

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Not sure what's going on here but `button` elements do not use `href` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

change the href to onclick

```
<button class="button1" onclick="javascript:validate(); return false;">Validate</button>
```

it works! ( no pun intended )

Comment: That was a mistake i did in here while pasting the code I edited my question. It doesn't work :(

Comment: it works for me... did you by any chance check the box that says prevent firefox grom opening the alerts etc... if you did or unsure, then restart browser, clear cookies history etc and try reloading again

Comment: lol Yep, the problem was with the cache and cookies, cleared all out, restarted FF, and it works now. Cheers :).

Comment: glad to be of help :) please be sure to check/accept the answer above